# Ember router with optional dynamic segments and unkown order

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to setup a router with dynamic segments where the order is unknow?

I am developing an SPA where two of the major components are the search pane and the content pane. In the content pane you can navigate the links and the new content is loaded in the content pane.

You can also search and display a list of results in the search pane. Clicking a search result will update the content pane. In addition to these requirements, the user needs to be able to click a named-anchor link and scroll to a specific spot in the content.

The original router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.resource('page', {path: 'page/:page_id'}, function() {
        this.resource('anchor', {path: 'anchor/:anchor_id'});
        this.resource('search', {path: 'search/:search_id'});
    });
});
```

The problem with this router is I can have **/page/foo**, **/page/foo/anchor/001** and **/page/foo/search/terms** but I can't have **/page/foo/search/terms/anchor/001**. There will be need to add more routes as the app grows. The **page** route will always exist, but any others will be optional.

I'm hoping there is a way to add more flexibility in my router that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to sacrifice a small amount of DRYness, this works:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('page', {path: 'page/:page_id'}, function() {
    this.resource('anchor', {path: 'anchor/:anchor_id'});
    this.resource('search', {path: 'search/:search_id'}, function(){
      this.resource('anchor', {path: 'anchor/:anchor_id'});
    });
  });
});
```

(note you have to use resource, if you use route the parent resource's namespace gets added to the generated v/c object names)